# is there a design pattern for an amqp architecture for commit/rollback message handling?

Tags: design-patterns, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a simple producer/consumer amqp set up like this:

```
producer -> e1:jobs_queue -> consumer -> e2:results_queue -> result_handler
```

The producer sends of some number of jobs. The consumer pulls down jobs one at a time, and processes them, pushing the result into another queue. These are then pulled out by the result_handler that publishes the results to a database.

Sometimes the consumer fails - it may get killed by the OS or throw an exception. If this happens while it is processing a message then this message is lost, no corresponding result is produced and I am sad. I would be happy again if the failed job was re-queued.

What I'm looking for is a design pattern for ensuring that either *consumer* processes the job to completion and puts a corresponding result into *results_queue*, or if it fails that the job is put back into *jobs_queue*. As *consumer* is what is failing, *consumer* should not be responsible for managing any messages relating to its own supervision.

We know that *consumer* has failed to process a job if:

- it took a job from *job_queue* and no result has been produced after some timeout
- it took a job from *job_queue* and then died

For my application, we can probably capture the 2nd case by simply waiting for processing of the job to time out. In production, there will be many workers to supervise, all pulling jobs from a common jobs list and putting results into a single results exchange/queue.

Comment: Are you auto-acking messages? Presumably you could turn off auto-ack and then ack once the job has been successfully processed, thereby having Rabbit take care of requeuing messages.

Comment: There are several patterns for reliable messaging, persistent message queues, acknowledged deliver, two stage acknowledgement (received & saved/forwarded) and several others.  This is not an easy quetion to answer with out detailed knowledge of your platform and requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to manually handle acknowledgements for messages received. In `node-amqp` it's as simple as adding the option `{ ack: true }` to the `queue.subscribe` call. You can then acknowledge messages by calling some function on the queue. In case of `node-amqp` it's `queue.shift()`.

You can also set the number of not-yet-acknowledged messages the consumer is allowed, using `prefetchCount`.

Any unacknowledged messages will now be redelivered (to any connected consumers) if the consumer disconnects.

By also setting the queue to `durable` and `autoDelete: false`, you can additionally make sure that the queue (and messages on it) will not be deleted upon restart of your MQ-server or disconnection of the last consumer.